# Is there any usage of Lucene.Net.Linq and database (EF)?

Tags: .net, linq-to-lucene

There is no example of database usage at the [documentation](https://github.com/themotleyfool/Lucene.Net.Linq/wiki/README)

I know the lib [LinqToLucene](http://linqtolucene.codeplex.com/), but I want to try Lucene.Net.Linq.

Help me please to find any example.

Comment: Did you manage to find any examples?

Comment: I worked with this lib like in documantation. At first I filled the index(once) and then I update this index when add/inset/delete data.

Answer (score 2):

As the creator of Lucene.Net.Linq, I can say that there is no built in support for integrating Lucene.Net.Linq with EF or other database providers. This library is designed to allow LINQ to be used with a Lucene index, plain and simple. It makes no assumptions about how data gets into the index. That is up to the client to do.

Comment: Hi, Chris. Would you happen to have a simple example of "Add, delete and update documents in atomic transaction" as per the README?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer sure, but that's unrelated to this question. Please ask a new question and I'd be happy to put an example in an answer there.

Comment: Done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130281/would-like-to-see-an-example-of-adding-documents-in-lucene-net-linq